# Addressing the Parent DOM in jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html, parent

I have a webpage that generated the same DIV according to categories in a database using a simple query. So in this case there are two categories.  Each DIV has a button that when clicked should change the text of the current DIVs titleText.

```
<body>

<div class="DOMParent" style="width: 100%; border: 1px solid #ff0000; margin: 10px; padding:10px;">
    <div class="title">
        <div class="titleText">Category 1</div>
        <button id="btn">id="btn" Click Me</button>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="DOMParent" style="width: 100%; border: 1px solid #ff0000; margin: 10px; padding:10px;">
    <div class="title">
        <div class="titleText">Category 2</div>
        <button id="btn">id="btn" Click Me</button>
    </div>
</div>


<script>

    dp("#btn").click(function(){
        dp(".titleText").html("This is the new TITLE Text");
    });

</script>

</body>
```

My problem is that in Category 1 for example, if I click that button then it will change the html for both titleText when it should only change the html for the titleText in Category 1.

I have tried using incremental ids and all sorts which are definitely not the answer. So how to I change the titleText only in the Button's current DOMParent div?

This sample code is written just to simplify my problem so that the code is much smaller. I have left out the mysql query and sorts because in the end this is literally what is generated.

Comment: `ID should always be unique` use `different ID` and this should work. change second button with id `btn` to something else

Comment: Not the answer. Remember that the entire div DOMParent is created for each category in the database. So if there are 4 Categories, then there will be 4 of these divs

Comment: can you check this demo if this is what you wanted https://jsfiddle.net/guradio/9ov7wLxh/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**id property is unique value**, so you need to change buttons id attribute to **class**.

```
<button class="btn"> Click Me</button>
```

and now you want to access parent, so you should use **[parent()](https://api.jquery.com/parent/)** method of jQuery. and then you need to find children `.titleText` with [**find**](https://api.jquery.com/find/) method.

So you can write code like this, and check below example fiddle

```
$(this).parent().find(".titleText").text("This is the new TITLE Text");
```

**[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/f1esvjqj/)**

Comment: Perfect. That is exactly what I have been looking for. Thank you very much.

Comment: @FunnyGirl really funny :)

Answer (score 0):

As **'IDs must be unique'**,  You can provide a common `class` to the `button` like this:

```
<div class="DOMParent" style="width: 100%; border: 1px solid #ff0000; margin: 10px; padding:10px;">
<div class="title">
    <div class="titleText">Category 1</div>
    <button class="btn">id="btn" Click Me</button>
</div>
</div>
<div class="DOMParent" style="width: 100%; border: 1px solid #ff0000; margin: 10px; padding:10px;">
<div class="title">
    <div class="titleText">Category 2</div>
    <button class="btn">id="btn" Click Me</button>
</div>
```

And then in JS use `prev` to get the previous `div` with `class titleText` like this:

```
dp(".btn").click(function(){ 
    dp(this).prev(".titleText").html("This is the new TITLE Text");
});
```

The `.prev()` method searches for the predecessor of each of these elements in the DOM tree and constructs a new jQuery object from the matching elements.

The method optionally accepts a selector expression of the same type that can be passed to the `$()` function. If the selector is supplied, the preceding element will be filtered by testing whether it match the selector.

Here is the [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/f9852zu0/) for the same

Answer (score 0):

You have to use class for buttons not id, and find the siblings of it.

```
<body>

<div class="DOMParent" style="width: 100%; border: 1px solid #ff0000; margin: 10px; padding:10px;">
<div class="title">
    <div class="titleText">Category 1</div>
    <button class="btn">id="btn" Click Me</button>
</div>
</div>

<div class="DOMParent" style="width: 100%; border: 1px solid #ff0000;  margin: 10px; padding:10px;">
<div class="title">
    <div class="titleText">Category 2</div>
    <button class="btn">id="btn" Click Me</button>
</div>
</div>


<script>

$("#btn").click(function() {
  $(this).siblings(".titleText").html("This is the new TITLE Text");
});

</script>

</body>
```

Comment: in html you are using `class` but in js you are using `#`

Comment: it's a typo, sorry for that. you have to use (".btn") instead of ("#btn").